# Is there a way to select a range dynamically in a macro based on cursor position?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy rows from columns A to CO but the row will be different each time. I would like to copy the range of A:CO based on the postion of the cursor.

```
Range("A6:CO6").Copy
    Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Sheets("Active").Select
    Rows("6:6").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

I would like to pick the row with cursor postion and have the range of A:CO copy to the Completed sheet. I have this macro working but only for row 6.

Comment: `activecell.row`?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `.Copy` row with this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveCell.Row & ":CO" & ActiveCell.Row).Copy
```

It builds a range string based on the `ActiveCell.Row`, similar to what you are doing on row 2 in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution using resize.

```
ActiveCell.Resize(, 93).Copy
Sheets("Completed").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```